# Should "scheduling" be renamed, questions re-tagged or just the description updated?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspiration was [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181569/what-is-the-functionality-of-sched-softirq-in-linux) which was mistakenly tagged [scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) even though the description on the tag page seems to be saying it's for `crond` and `atd` scheduled jobs.

However [some other people seem to have taken it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) to mean what I would have assumed it meant: determining the share and order of some sort of operation (Disk I/O, network packet queuing, CPU time, etc).

This seems like an issue with organization. Should the description updated or should these be re-tagged with something else and leave [scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) to mean `crond`/`atd`?

Comment: Wow, that tag is a mess! Personally I would have thought scheduling referred to process, I/O, etc. scheduling, not cron. Maybe someone from Redmond decided on the tag description? (I think Windows calls its cron-like feature Task Scheduler).

Comment: We should disambiguate, maybe [tag:task-scheduling] or [tag:job-scheduling] for `cron` and the like, and [tag:process-scheduler] for CPU time sharing, and [tag:io-sheduler] for disk/network/… time sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure splitting process and I/O scheduling is really worth it, as they're often deeply interconnected anyway. (E.g., if a process is waiting on I/O, it can't be scheduled to run). Also, network scheduling is more normally called QoS, rate limiting, or traffic shaping, and is configured differently than disk I/O scheduling, so I wouldn't include it in I/O scheduling. I'd suggest keeping [scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) the refer to process and I/O scheduling, though would not object to splitting that to [process-scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-scheduling) and either [disk-scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disk-scheduling) or [io-scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/io-scheduling).

[Job scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler) is, I think, *not* normally used to refer to cron-style "run this at 01:03 every Sunday"; it's closer to what `batch` does. Though would often be used across a cluster. So I wouldn't use that.

Task Scheduler is the name of a Windows component. It's also quite close to multitasking, which is what process (and I/O) scheduling does. Further, "task" isn't normal Unix terminology. So I wouldn't suggest that.

The cron manpage describes it as a "daemon to execute scheduled commands". So I'd suggest [command-scheduling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-scheduling).